# Convert string to enum with orika mapper in java

Tags: java, enums, orika

I have an enum class

```
public enum ProductLocaleEnum {
    EN_US("en_US"), FR_FR("fr_FR"), ES_ES("es_ES");

    private String locale;
    ProductLocaleEnum(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }
}
```

I have my destination class where one of the property is defined as of type ProductLocaleEnum

```
public class IssuingAuthorityDestination {
    private String name;
    private ProductLocaleEnum locale;
}
```

My source looks like:

```
public class IssuingAuthoritySource {
    private String name;
    private String locale;
}
```

When I try to use Orika mapper to map from Source to destination i get an error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.accenture.helix.catalog.bean.ProductLocaleEnum.en_US.
```

How to convert String to Enum while mapping from source to destination?

Comment: You need to extend CustomMapper abstract class, and override mapAtoB and mapBtoA methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement converter - class that inherits from CustomConverter and converts string to enumeration.
In your case it should look like this:

```
public class StringToProductLocaleEnumConverter extends CustomConverter<String, ProductLocaleEnum> {

    @Override
    public ProductLocaleEnum convert(String source, Type<? extends ProductLocaleEnum> destinationType, MappingContext mappingContext) {
        return Arrays.stream(ProductLocaleEnum.values()).filter(p -> p.getLocale().equals(source)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }

}
```

then add the the converter to converter factory:

```
private class ProductMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {

    @Override
    protected void configure(MapperFactory factory) {
            ConverterFactory converterFactory = factory.getConverterFactory();
            converterFactory.registerConverter(new StringToProductLocaleEnumConverter());
            ....
    }
}
```